# Как сверстать блоки с треугольными закладками?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как сверстать блоки с такими закладками (треугольниками) как на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block4 {
  background-color: gray;
}

.block5 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.block6 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.block7 {
  background-color: coral;
}

.block8 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1"></div>
<div class="block block2"></div>
<div class="block block3"></div>
<div class="block block4"></div>
<div class="block block5"></div>
<div class="block block6"></div>
<div class="block block7"></div>
<div class="block block8"></div>
```

Comment: у вас вопрос про треугольничек этот?

Comment: @teran, да. Такие квадраты с маленькими треугольниками.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```css
body,html {margin: 0;padding: 0;}

.blocks {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-reset: albumList;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
}

.block:before {
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.block:nth-child(1):before,
.block:nth-child(2):before,
.block:nth-child(3):before {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.block:nth-child(4):before {
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.block:nth-child(5):before {
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.block:nth-child(6):before,
.block:nth-child(7):before,
.block:nth-child(8):before {
  left: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -7px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
  transform: rotateZ(45deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(1):before,
.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(2):before,
.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(3):before {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(4):before {
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(5):before {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(6):before,
.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(7):before,
.blocks:hover .block:nth-child(8):before {
  left: 12px;
}

.block:after {
  counter-increment: albumList;
  content: counter(albumList);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 4% 7%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.33) inset;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.block1 {background-color: red;}
.block2 {background-color: green;}
.block3 {background-color: blue;}
.block4 {background-color: gray;}
.block5 {background-color: aquamarine;}
.block6 {background-color: bisque;}
.block7 {background-color: coral;}
.block8 {background-color: black;}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block block1"></div>
  <div class="block block2"></div>
  <div class="block block3"></div>
  <div class="block block4"></div>
  <div class="block block5"></div>
  <div class="block block6"></div>
  <div class="block block7"></div>
  <div class="block block8"></div>
</div>
```

*Треугольники появляются при наведении на родительский блок*

Comment: На мой взгляд, хорошее, полезное решение. Было бы неплохо, где-нибудь упомянуть, об интерактивности вкладок Я вот не сразу, например заметил, что при наведении появляются треугольники.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да какие там замечания :) Просто дружеский совет, чтобы люди мимо  хорошего ответа не проходили

Comment: Начиная с 22ой строки и по 29 вы задаете - `.block:nth-child(1):before` , но почему бы не сократить до `.block:before` , по-сути 8 строчек лишнего кода.

Comment: Пример отличный, плюс оставил!

Answer (score 5):

Ну а размер там уже самомтоятельно определяй ;) Но, кажется, то, что надо.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}
.block:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateZ(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block4 {
  background-color: gray;
}

.block5 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.block6 {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.block7 {
  background-color: coral;
}

.block8 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1"></div>
<div class="block block2"></div>
<div class="block block3"></div>
<div class="block block4"></div>
<div class="block block5"></div>
<div class="block block6"></div>
<div class="block block7"></div>
<div class="block block8"></div>
```